# Baseboard heater breaker tripping

Tags: circuit-breaker, heater, baseboard

One of the breakers on a 240V two-baseboard circuit trips as soon as the thermostat is turned up enough to turn it on. It is not the thermostat as I changed that for a known good one. Can I fault-find the problem with just an ohm-meter?

Comment: Before you start with the meter, just have a good think if someone has fixed a loose panel by the heater anywhere or put a screw back and used a longer one...

Comment: Possible if it is a short that is causing it(good chance).  It should narrow down where to look closely for the problem.  Do have the breaker turned off.

Comment: You say "2 breakers on 1 circuit", can you post a photo of the breakers in question?  Do their handles move independently?  Do they have a "test" button?

Comment: **One of the breakers** - A 240V appliance, like a typical baseboard heater, should be designed & installed so that the breakers (a) are always next to each other and (b) always trip together for safety. So if you have a pair and one trips but not the other, that is an indication of a problem. Does your thermostat have two wires connected (one in, one out) or four wires (two in, two out)? A picture of all wires in the thermostat junction box would be helpful. And a picture of the breakers.

Comment: The OP may have meant by "one of the breakers" being an honest 240 V breaker. We'll need to get a resp to be sure. It would be unusual for base board heat to be supplied by 2 independent breakers, but could be if someone hacked it together.  Still, tripping breakers is really REALLY BAD and indicates a serious problem.   To diagnose (which I'm   a big fan of!), would be to turn off the power and VERIFY that the power is off, disconnect the connections AT THE BASEBOARDS, cap them and then turn on the power and turn up the Tstat, if it still trips, you have a cabling problem. Maybe rodents.

Comment: ...continuing, if it doesn't trip, one of your baseboard heaters has a true short, NOT GOOD, dangerous.